# Gradle cannot resolve Spring Boot HATEOAS dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I created my skeleton project from http://start.spring.io . But when I build the application, Gradle cannot resolve the HATEOAS dependency. Here is the error I get:

> Error:java: Illegal char <:> at index 78:
>   C:\Users\TempUser\Downloads\hateoas\Could not resolve
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.0.4.RELEASE.

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.0.4.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't specify the version for the spring-boot-starter dependencies. Look at the other three dependencies you have - make the failing one look like those! :)

Comment: which dependencies have you specified in the Spring initializr? Have you added the HATEOAS dependency manually?

Comment: I specified the web, jpa and hateoas dependency while creating the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.0.4.RELEASE')
```

cause error. Change to

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
```

This is what under the hood
[image]

Comment: I removed the version but I still have the same bug.

Comment: I have removed the version number but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I use your file `build.gradle` and no problem https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/44404190-92acdf80-a580-11e8-9b3b-caee553325eb.png

Comment: Try to install latest version of Gradle (4.9), and check fireware, proxy, delete all Maven local.

Comment: Thanks @Do Nhu Vy. The problem was my proxy. I had to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

You've already specified the spring boot components' version right here:

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}
```

Hence, all *starter* dependencies must be specified without the version value. Use:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
```

instead of

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.0.4.RELEASE')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have removed the version number but I still have thesame error message.